# Microphone isn't working in Skype or sound recorder. Has an extreme lag

Tags: sound, skype, microphone

I'm new to Ubuntu and am using 11.04. I've been trying to Skype with a friend for a week now and my microphone isn't working. I didn't have this problem using Windows, so it's not the internal microphone. I also tried plugging in an external microphone, and that didn't work either. I've played around in sound settings and finally got the external microphone to work in both Skype and sound recorder, but it has a drastic lag in both. My voice ends up sounding really slowed down and deep to the other person. Anyone else having this problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem except that my voice sounds like a chipmonk on steroids.  I am running Ubuntu 11.10.  See if there are drivers available for your web-cam or microphone that support Ubuntu/Linux on the manufacturer's web site.  This may resolve your problem.

Comment: can you paste the output of the command,"lspci" without quotes in terminal, and add it to your question? and describe the skype audio settings you have?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!